# Android: how to show the user which view is active

Tags: android, android-scrollbar

I have an activity with a `WebView`. I would like to give the possibility to the user to scroll from one `WebView` to another `WebView` (as it's done to Android desktop):

[image: image1]

with something in the bottom which shows which screen is actually viewed. I have think about the `ScrollView` but maybe  something else exists which easier to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what you want to use is the ViewPager
http://android-developers.blogspot.de/2011/08/horizontal-view-swiping-with-viewpager.html

To get an indicator which shows on what page the user is use:
http://jakewharton.com/viewpagerindicator/

An example how to use it is here:
http://blog.stylingandroid.com/archives/537

Comment: I have a problem using the ViewPager, how to get the  android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;

Comment: you can find a step by step introduction here http://developer.android.com/sdk/compatibility-library.html

Comment: Great, finally I am able to use the ViewPager. If you have an easy example of ViewPagerIndicator, it would be great. Thanks again for all your help